# Confusing t-sql exam answer about sequence or uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I found a t-sql question and its answer. It is too confusing. I could use a little help.

The question is:

You develop a database application. You create four tables. Each table stores different categories of products. You create a Primary Key field on each table.

You need to ensure that the following requirements are met:

- The fields must use the minimum amount of space.
- The fields must be an incrementing series of values.
- The values must be unique among the four tables.

What should you do?

- A. Create a `ROWVERSION` column.
- B. Create a `SEQUENCE` object that uses the `INTEGER` data type.
- C. Use the `INTEGER` data type along with `IDENTITY`
- D. Use the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` data type along with `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`
- E. Create a `TIMESTAMP` column.

The said answer is D. But, I think the more suitable answer is B. Because sequence will use less space than GUID and it satisfies all the requirements.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is if the author was thinking of a way that records from two tables could somehow end up with the same SEQUENCE value. The other possibility is to set different starting values on identity columns, spread evenly across the range. Cuts you down to about 1/2 billion possible records in any table before you have collisions, but you'll be very lucky to ever have that many records in a Products table. This means option C could technically work, too.

Comment: I don't know what you are using for exam preparation but it seems pretty bad based on this and [your other recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37045757/73226)

Answer (score 3):

D is a wrong answer, because [`NEWSEQUENTIALID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) doesn't guarantee "an incrementing series of values" (second requirement).

> `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`
>
> Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID
>   previously generated by this function on a specified computer since
>   Windows was started. After restarting Windows, the GUID **can start
>   again from a lower range**, but is still globally unique.

I'd say that B (`sequence`) is the correct answer. At least, you can use a `sequence` to fulfil all three requirements, if you don't restart/recycle it manually. I think it is the easiest way to meet all three requirements.

Comment: and the end of the sentence is **, but is still globally unique.**

Comment: Yep. The correct answer is B. If you don't want it to cycle just create it as `NOCYCLE` and it can be created on a narrow datatype and applied as the default to multiple tables without any of them getting assigned the same values.

Comment: Quick search using favourite search engine and it looks like `70-457` exam and correct answer is B

Comment: @ZoharPeled, you are right, `NEWSEQUENTIALID` does generate unique GUIDs, but my point was that even though `NEWSEQUENTIALID` satisfies the third requirement (the values must be unique among the four tables), `NEWSEQUENTIALID` doesn't satisfy the second requirement (an incrementing series of values).

Comment: You are correct. I do have to admit that my answer was wrong and the correct option is B and not D. Will edit that when I have some time.

Answer (score 1):

Between the choices provided <strike>D</strike> B is the correct answer, since it meets all requirements:

`ROWVERSION`  is a bad choice for a primary key, as [stated in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx):

> Every time that a row with a rowversion column is modified or inserted, the incremented database rowversion value is inserted in the rowversion column. This property makes a rowversion column a poor candidate for keys, especially primary keys. Any update made to the row changes the rowversion value and, therefore, changes the key value. If the column is in a primary key, the old key value is no longer valid, and foreign keys referencing the old value are no longer valid.

`TIMESTAMP` is deprecated, as stated in that same page:

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

An `IDENTITY` column does not guarantee uniqueness, unless all it's values are only ever generated automatically (you can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` to insert values manually), nor does it guarantee uniqueness between tables for any value.

A `GUID` is practically guaranteed to be unique per system, so if a `guid` is the primary key for all 4 tables it ensures uniqueness for all tables. the one requirement it **doesn't fulfill** is storage size - It's storage size is quadruple that of int (16 bytes instead of 4).

A `SEQUENCE`, when is not [declared as recycle, guarantee uniqueness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx), and has the lowest storage size.

> The sequence of numeric values is generated in an ascending or descending order at a defined interval and can be configured to restart (cycle) when exhausted.

**However**, 
I would actually probably choose a different option all together - create a base table with a single identity column and link it with a 1:1 relationship with all other categories. then use an instead of insert trigger for all categories tables that will first insert a record to the base table and then use `scope_identity()` to get the value and insert it as the primary key for the category table. 
This will enforce uniqueness as well as make it possible to use a single foreign key reference between the categories and products.

Comment: `int` is 4 bytes. `sequence` doesn't have to be recycled. [`NEWSEQUENTIALID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) is not guaranteed to be incrementing. Your different option is a hand-made `sequence`.

Comment: I favour creating additional table too - original db structure seems really painful to maintain and query. Actually single table for different kind of products would be even better; you can 'hide' unneccessary fields using views and so on.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov thanls,  I was thinking about bigInt. will fix that. but my different option differs from a sequence on one big parameter - it can be used as a foreign key as I've explained in my answer.

Comment: Along with the special cases for identity and sequences not being unique (i.e. special intervention), a GUID can also not be unique of you explicitly insert a values just like you propose for identity. The problem with all these MS exam questions is that there is not enough context. You could certainly solve this with a sequence if you never explicitly recycled it.

Comment: Yes, you can manually insert an existing guid to a guid column. I agree. but the more important point I was making about the identity is that it's on a single table level.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I see. I didn't pay attention to the foreign key part of your suggestion. Sorry. BTW, in practice the trigger that you describe will be more tricky that just a `scope_identity()`, because it is possible to insert several rows at once in one `INSERT` statement. The trigger should be able to handle that.

Comment: Yes Identity is out it's either GUID or sequence, and both of these can be 'manually overwritten'

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been discussed extensively in the past, in general:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/

The constraint #3 is why a `SEQUENCE` could run into issues as there is a higher risk of collision/lowered number of possible rows in each table.