# do these facts really hint to use FORCESEEK or not?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The said answer for the following question is C to use FORCESEEK hint. But, to use hint, we have to review the execution plan first, right? The question doesn't mention anything about execution plan. The problem seems to be "Readers block Writers". So, won't SNAPSHOT ISOLATION help in this kind of situation?

Question:
A database application runs slowly because of a query against a frequently updated table that has a clustered index. The query returns four columns: three columns in its where clause contained in a non-clustered index and one additional column. To optimize the statement

- A. Add a HASH hint to the query
- B. Add a LOOP hint to the query
- C. Add a FORCESEEK hint to the query
- D. Add an INCLUDE clause to the index
- E. Add a FORCESCAN hint to the attach query
- F. Add a columnstore index to cover the query
- G. Enable the optimize for ad hoc workloads option.
- H. Conver the unique clustered index with a columnstore index.
- I. Include a SET FORCEPLAN ON statement before you run the query
- J. Include a SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON statement before you run the query
- K. Include a SET STATISTICS SHOWPLAN_XML ON statement before you run the query
- L. Include a SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ statement before you run the query
- M. Include a SET TRANSADCTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT statement before you run the query
- N. Include a SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE statement before you run the query

Comment: It's an interesting question, so I'm going to upvote.

Comment: You could interpret the question two ways: either (i) the slow execution is due to the frequent updates, or (ii) it's to do with the non-clustered index. In the real-world, we would certainly want to examine the execution plan, and also know how many records will be returned by the query. (C) is not a good answer, because the Query Optimizer is almost always good at its job. In the absence of more information, I would opt for (D), so the non-clustered index covers the query.

Comment: Unfortunately the people that write these questions often don't really seem  to have a good grasp on the topic themselves. There is no way sufficient information in the question to conclude (C) is required. We don't know if the predicate using these columns is even sargable or anything about cardinality.

Comment: It looks like you are preparing for one of MS Cert exam. Good advice for you: do not rely on sb question dump. Install SQL Server Developer edition, get exam objectives and learn/try each topic.

Comment: @lad2025 Yes. I am preparing for 70-461 exam. I am working in SAP+SQL Server environment.

Answer (score 1):

I will go for option D. because it covers the missing non-Clusterd Index on the table.